# Is saveAll() of MongoRepository inserting data in one bulk?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I want to make the save operation efficient, so I'd like to write a bulk of objects to Mongo once in a while (i.e. when exceeding some capacity)

Would `saveAll()` do that for me? Should I use `BulkOperations` instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer, **yes, but only if all documents are new**. If not, it will insert or update one by one.

Take a look at *SimpleMongoRepository* (*MongoRepository's* default implementation):

```
public <S extends T> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {
        Assert.notNull(entities, "The given Iterable of entities not be null!");
        Streamable<S> source = Streamable.of(entities);
        boolean allNew = source.stream().allMatch((it) -> {
            return this.entityInformation.isNew(it);
        });
        if (allNew) {
            List<S> result = (List)source.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
            return new ArrayList(this.mongoOperations.insert(result, this.entityInformation.getCollectionName()));
        } else {
            return (List)source.stream().map(this::save).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Notice that when all documents are new, the repository will use *MongoOperations.insert* method (*MongoTemplate* is the implementation), **Then, if you look at that method's code you'll realize it does a batch insert:**

```
public <T> Collection<T> insert(Collection<? extends T> batchToSave, String collectionName) {
        Assert.notNull(batchToSave, "BatchToSave must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(collectionName, "CollectionName must not be null!");
        return this.doInsertBatch(collectionName, batchToSave, this.mongoConverter);
    }
```

---

**UPDATE 2021:**

As of spring-data-mongodb 1.9.0.RELEASE (current 3.2.2), BulkOperations comes with a lot of extra features.

If more advanced tasks are needed other than just saving a bunch of documents, then [BulkOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/BulkOperations.html) class is the way to go.

It covers bulk inserts, updates, and deletes:

- insert(List<? extends Object> documents)
- remove(List removes)
- updateMulti(List<Pair<Query,Update>> updates)

Comment: @lewik, probably a bit late, but i just updated the answer

Comment: will spring-data-mongodb care about Optmistic Lock versioning when using BulkOperations?

Comment: @SamueldeOliveiraMarques AFAIK optimistic locking is not tied to BulkOperations themselves, but rather to the use of Version annotation. So i guess that as long as  each field has been annotated with Version, BulkOperations should honor it.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.optimistic-locking