# Why does it takes longer to saveAll() than to save() in MongoDB Spring Data?

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

```
12:27:25.300 | save 10000 entities with saveAll() has been done in 110.869 sec.
12:29:11.474 | save 10000 entities with save() has been done in 105.925 sec.
```

I used `saveAll()` instead `save()` for better performance but the result was against my expectations...

Comment: Why did you have the assumption that `saveAll(...)` should be faster than `save(...)`? --- Have you repeated the experiment? A single point of data is not very convincing.

Comment: What is the output of your profiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996227/is-saveall-of-mongorepository-inserting-data-in-one-bulk indicates that saveAll will use a batch insert IF all the documents are new. If not it falls back to regular save. As Turing85 suggested you need to repeat many times to get useful statistics though!

Comment: I was test it in **postgreSQL** that `saveAll(...)` is very faster than `save(...)` in it. @Turing85